# Find consecutive True and False within a nested list of based on condition

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list with `((x, y), (w, h), True/False)` values, for example consider the following list:

```
ls = [[(300, 765), (24, 24), False], [(300, 766), (23, 22), False], [(300, 734), (24, 24), False],
      [(300, 734), (23, 23), False], [(556, 734), (23, 23), True], [(300, 701), (24, 24), False],
      [(301, 702), (22, 23), False], [(300, 668), (24, 24), False], [(301, 669), (22, 23), False],
      [(300, 578), (24, 24), False], [(301, 579), (22, 22), False], [(300, 544), (24, 24), False],
      [(301, 545), (22, 23), False], [(300, 513), (24, 24), False], [(301, 513), (22, 23), False],
      [(300, 478), (27, 26), False], [(300, 481), (24, 22), True], [(216, 394), (23, 23), True]]
```

I need to  find consecutive True and False elements where the difference each element of the `(x, y)` pairs are less than `5`.

The following snipped code works fine but looking for more optimized way.

```
array = np.array(ls)
for i in range(len(array) - 1):
     if (abs(array[i][0][0] - array[i + 1][0][0]) < 5)  & \
             (abs(array[i][0][1] - array[i + 1][0][1]) < 5) & \
             ((array[i][2] == False) & (array[i + 1][2] == True)):
        print('i', array[i])
        print('i+1', array[i + 1])
```

Comment: What you have here is `O(n)` and I don't think it can be done in anything less.

Comment: @venky__. If course you can. O(1000*n) is still O(n)

Comment: @Elham. Can you modify your data structure to make a list of tuples?

Comment: A) I didn't mean just change the title of the post. I meant make the initialization of `ls` have tuples (e.g., `((300, 765), (24, 24), False)` instead of `[(300, 765), (24, 24), False]`, and B) that's not how you spell tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control of your data structure, record the elements of `ls` as tuples rather than lists:

```
ls = [((300, 765), (24, 24), False),
      ((300, 766), (23, 22), False),
      ((300, 734), (24, 24), False),
      ((300, 734), (23, 23), False),
      ((556, 734), (23, 23), True),
      ((300, 701), (24, 24), False),
      ((301, 702), (22, 23), False),
      ((300, 668), (24, 24), False),
      ((301, 669), (22, 23), False),
      ((300, 578), (24, 24), False),
      ((301, 579), (22, 22), False),
      ((300, 544), (24, 24), False),
      ((301, 545), (22, 23), False),
      ((300, 513), (24, 24), False),
      ((301, 513), (22, 23), False),
      ((300, 478), (27, 26), False),
      ((300, 481), (24, 22), True),
      ((216, 394), (23, 23), True)]
```

If you don't have that control, run `ls = list(map(tuple, ls))` after the fact.

Now you can make an array of the list like this:

```
pair = np.dtype([('a', int), ('b', int)])
item = np.dtype([('xy', pair), ('wh', pair), ('tf', bool)])
a = np.array(ls, dtype=item)
```

Now you can create a mask of the locations of interest:

```
mask = a['tf'][1:] & ~a['tf'][:-1] & (np.abs(np.diff(a['xy']['a'])) < 5) & (np.abs(np.diff(a['xy']['b'])) < 5)
```

Turn the mask into linear indices to get the locations you want:

```
indices = np.flatnonzero(mask)
```

If you want an array of both the current and next index:

```
np.stack((indices, indices + 1), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use numpy efficiently you have to adjust the data slightly. It would be even better if you store / generate the data in a more uniform way.
Right now its a nested list(tuple(list(...))) structure which is hard to read for numpy and `np.array(ls)` returns an object array where you can't access the columns easily.

```py
# Get arrays
xy = np.array([l[0] for l in ls])
b = np.array([l[2] for l in ls])

# Get hits for xy and True / False
xy_bool = (np.diff(xy, axis=0) < 5).sum(axis=1) == 2
b_bool = np.logical_and(b[:-1], b[1:])

# Combine hits
idx = np.nonzero(np.logical_and(xy_bool, b_bool))[0]
idx = np.vstack((idx-1, idx)).T

# array[idx]
# array([[[(300, 478), (27, 26), False],
#         [(300, 481), (24, 22), True]]], dtype=object)
```

For this array size there is no real speed gain using numpy, but if you make it lets say 1000x bigger I got an improvement of factor 20x on my machine.